# how to implement Floating-Navigation-View in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, floating-action-button

i am trying to implement floating navigation-view which look like this[image]

please help me how to implement this...thank you in advance

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

try this:
plz check this demo: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4134

Include the library in your build.gradle

```
dependencies{
compile 'com.github.andremion:floatingnavigationview:1.0.0'
}
```